# VBA pasting information from a form onto the next open line in a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following form:

[image]

When user clicks the "Submit Adjustment" button, I want the information in the yellow boxes (plus the date on that line) entered into the following table

[image]

Here's the code I'm using:

```
Sub LOG_CHG()
  Sheets("ENTER CHG").Range("B8:I8").Copy
  Sheets("CHANGE LOG").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1). _
    PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  MsgBox ("Your adjustment has been logged.")
   Range("C8:I8").Select

   Selection.ClearContents
   Range("C8").Select

End Sub
```

This is happening somewhat successfully, but sometimes it gets lost and pastes at the bottom of the table or in random places.

**How can I make sure it pastes the information in the next available row?**

Comment: I just deleted the CHANGE LOG tab, re-created it and set up the table to paste into. Now it's only going to the end of the table and adding a row every time. I've deleted everything in column A so there's nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

Sheets("CHANGE LOG").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

This line means Excel is checking sheet "change log" from last Excel line in column **A** up until it finds any symbol in cell. And offset(1) means 1 row down. For example:

You have something written in A32(space, number or letter), but from A33 to A1000000+ row is nothing --> so your code will paste everything in A33.

In other words Select A1000000 and press Ctrl+UP.

Comment: Note: the `Rows.Count` is unqualified. It should read: `Sheets("CHANGE LOG").Cells(Sheets("CHANGE LOG").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)....`

Comment: I just deleted the CHANGE LOG tab, re-created it and set up the table to paste into. Now it's only going to the end of the table and adding a row every time. I've deleted everything in column A so there's nothing there. What could be the issue?

Comment: As CLR said, Rows.Count gets active sheet rows count, not your "change log". 
And try Sheets("CHANGE LOG").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select,  check what does it select.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a table on the log-sheet you can access it via the `listobject`which is pretty easy to program against.

```vb
Public Sub log_chg()

Dim rgSource As Range
Set rgSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter chg").Range("B8:I8")

Dim loChangeLog As ListObject
Set loChangeLog = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Change log").ListObjects(1)

Dim lrTarget As ListRow
Set lrTarget = lo.ListRows.Add

lrTarget.Range.Value = rgSource.Value

End Sub
```

No need to check for the last row or anything.
`ListRow`is always appended to the end of the table.

As the ranges of the source and the target are of same size you can write the value like shown in the code.

What you should do before testing: delete all the empty rows of the log table.